# C++ - Not breaking out of loop

Tags: c++

I am creating a program to calculate standard deviation and average. When the user inputs '#' the program should display the results rounded to two decimal points. My code gets the values, but when i input '#' the program doesnt exit the 4 look and display the block in the else if statement. it just crashes the IDE. Code is below.

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
vector<double> myValues;
double val = 0.00;
int n = 1;
double sum = 0.00;
double average = 0.00;
double sumStandDif = 0.00;
double standDev = 0.00;

for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    cout << "Enter value " << n << ":";
    cin >> val;
    myValues.push_back(val);

    if (to_string(val) !=  "#"){
        sum = sum + myValues[i];
        average = sum/myValues.size();
        n += 1;

    }else if(to_string(val) == "#"){
        i = n + 1;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < myValues.size() - 1 ; j++){
            sumStandDif +=  (myValues[j] - average)*(myValues[j] - average);
        }
        standDev = sqrt((1/(myValues.size() -1))*sumStandDif);
        cout << "The average is " << average;
        cout << "The standard deviation is " <<  standDev;
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:SOLUTION**

```
 using namespace std;   //allow access to all symbols in std namespace

int main(){                     //main method
vector<double> myValues;    //initializes/contructs an empty vector, with no elements
string val;                 //declare string val (input value)
int n = 1;                  //declare and initialize and assign int n a value of 1
double sum = 0.00;          //declare and initialize sum
double average = 0.00;      //declare and initialize average
double sumStandDif = 0.00;  //declare and initialize sumStandDif
double standDev = 0.00;     //declare and initialize standDev

for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){               //declare and initialize for loop
    cout << "Enter value " << n << ": ";    //output stream, asks to enter a value
    cin >> val;                             //input stream, stores input value in string val
    if (val !=  "#"){                       //checks if the string val is #, if not then go into if block
        myValues.push_back(stod(val));      //Converts the value of string val to double and store it in the vector myVales
        sum = sum + myValues[i];            //Calculates the running sum of the values, while iterating over the for loop
        average = sum/myValues.size();      //Calculates the average of the values in myValues
        n += 1;                             //increment n by 1 to continue iterating over the for loop

    }else {                                                                             //if string val is equal to '#' proceed into else block
        for(int j = 0 ; j < myValues.size() ; j++){                                 //calculates the summation of (myValues[j]-average)^2 by iterating over for loop and not including '#'
            sumStandDif +=  (myValues[j] - average)*(myValues[j] - average);
        }
        standDev = sqrt((1.00/myValues.size())*sumStandDif);                    //Calculates the standard deviation once it calculates the summation
        cout << endl;                                                                   //new line
        cout << fixed << "The average is " << setprecision(2) << average;               //Output stream prints the average while rounding it to two decimals
        cout << endl;                                                                   //new line
        cout << fixed <<"The standard deviation is " << setprecision(2) << standDev;    //Output stream prints the standard deviation while rounding it to two decimals
        cout << endl;                                                                   //new line
        break;                                                                          //break/exit out of for-loop
    }
}
return 0;                   //terminate program
}
```

Comment: `val` is a `double`, it can neither receive `#` from `cin`, nor `to_string` to a "#".

Comment: You might want to do the opposite for the input, use a string and then use [`stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) instead to get the floating point value.

Comment: Voting to close as why is the code not working. Please generate a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **val** is not used in calculations it can be safely declared as string and **to_string** is not needed then.
Also,

```
}else if(to_string(val) == "#"){
```

can be just as simple as
 `}else{`

Answer (score 1):

`val` is a floating point value, so the user can never assign `#` to it using `cin`. Store `val` in a string first.

Answer (score 1):

you can change your code like this:

```
 string val;//declare val as string
then, after cin>>val check 
if(val!="#"){
   //convert string to double
   // insert double value into vector
   // do other work
}
else if(val=="#"){
// like your code.
}
```